# IndexError: too many indices for array , while taking care of missing data

Tags: python, numpy, scikit-learn

I am aware of that this same question has been asked many times before on SO, but I am really a novice in both python and machine learning, after trying for so many times without result , I am finally posting it here. So please pardon me for such question if possible.

I have a data set like this , in csv format

```
YearsExperience        Salary
1.1                    39343
1.3                    46205
1.5                    37731
2                      43525
2.2                    
2.9                    56642
```

As you can see for experience 2.2 the data for salary is missing , I tried to fill that with mean , and do something like following

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

# Importing the dataset
dataset = pd.read_csv('Salary_Data.csv')
X = dataset.iloc[:, :-1].values
y = dataset.iloc[:, 1].values

#taking care of missing data
#substitue missing value with the mean
from sklearn.preprocessing import Imputer
imputer = Imputer(missing_values='NaN',strategy='mean',axis=0)
imputer = imputer.fit(y[:,0:1])
y[:,0:1] = imputer.transform(y[:,0:1]);
```

and it gives me

```
IndexError: too many indices for array
```

But , if something is missing in `X` Like

```
YearsExperience        Salary
1.1                    39343
1.3                    46205
1.5                    37731
2                      43525
                       39891
2.9                    56642
```

and if I do the following , it automatically replace the missing value with `mean`

```
from sklearn.preprocessing import Imputer
imputer = Imputer(missing_values='NaN',strategy='mean',axis=0)
imputer = imputer.fit(X[:,0:1])
X[:,0:1] = imputer.transform(X[:,0:1]);
```

Comment: So, your second method works? What's your question?

Comment: @cᴏʟᴅsᴘᴇᴇᴅ , yes , it works , but it doesn't work , when something is missing in salary column . I tried the same thing for Salary but it gives me  IndexError ,  did I miss something ?

Comment: When you get an index error like this check the shape.  It might not be what you think.  In answering questions like this I frequently ask, 'what is the shape, dtype'.  It's never save to assume you know.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The mean reason your code fails is because `y` is a 1D array with shape -

```
X = df.iloc[:, :-1].values
y = df.iloc[:, 1].values

y.shape
(6,)
```

So, calling `y[:, 0:1]` on a 1D array is an invalid operation -

```
y[:,0:1]
IndexError: too many indices for array
```

Instead, what you should've done was initialise `y` as so -

```
y = df.iloc[:, -1:].values
```

Which would've made `y` a 2D array with one column, fixing the problem.

---

`imputer` accepts a 2D array with a single column, and returns a result of similar shape. Slice a single column dataframe, and pass it to `imputer.fit_transform`, which performs the fitting and transformation in a single step -

```
df['Salary'] = imputer.fit_transform(df[['Salary']]).ravel()
df

   YearsExperience   Salary
0              1.1  39343.0
1              1.3  46205.0
2              1.5  37731.0
3              2.0  43525.0
4              2.2  44689.2
5              2.9  56642.0
```

Comment: Thanks a lot , I never knew that it could be done in this way , it solves my problem  . by the way , if you have time,  could you kindly tell me , what did I do wrong ? though it works as expected for YearsExperience and I did the same thing for Salary . Both X and y are same time of variable , I just changed the variable name . Anyway thanks again .

Comment: @mSapps In your case, you do `y = dataset.iloc[:, 1].values`, so `y` is a `1D` array. Subsequently, doing `y[:,0:1]` is illegal. You get `IndexError: too many indices for array`.

Comment: @mSapps I've edited my answer, I hope it is clear now.

Comment: Now its clear to me . I don't know how to thank you . :)

Comment: @mSapps You have already thanked me enough by voting on, and accepting the answer. Happy coding!